# how perform a request to the telegram Bot API while sending an answer to the webhook?

Tags: php, telegram, telegram-bot

the Telegram API [say](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#making-requests-when-getting-updates):

> If you're using webhooks, you can perform a request to the Bot API while sending an answer to the webhook.

i try to do it by this simple code:

```
header('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
$content = http_build_query(array(
    'method' => 'sendMessage',
    'chat_id' => 123,
    'text' => 'test 123'
));
file_put_contents("php://output", $content); // or echo $content;
```

but i can't see any response in the robot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the Telegram update [robot API](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#recent-changes) in last day and now support JSON response.
so we can change the code:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode(array(
    'method'=>'sendMessage',
    'text'=>'test 123',
    'chat_id'=>123,
));
die;
```

and it works for me!

Comment: is it possible to send multiple messages in the json response? like 2 or 3 messages. maybe if we use an array.

Comment: @OmidSadeghi no